# nvd3 linechart with viewfinder not working with negative values

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js, linechart

I have following piece of code from the [example page](http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html) and used it once with only positive values and it worked. Now I have some negative values and the y-axis is not scaling any more correctly.

The graph in the viewfinder is also only positive and some realy large positive values are going through the top.

```
var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

var d = new Date();
chart.brushExtent([d.setHours(d.getHours() - 12), new Date()]);

chart.height(800);

chart.xAxis
  //.rotateLabels(-30)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%d.%m. %H:%M')(new Date(d));
  });

chart.x2Axis
  //.rotateLabels(-30)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%d.%m. %H:%M')(new Date(d));
  });

chart.yTickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true);

d3.select('#chartWrapper').append('svg')
  .datum(data)
  .transition().duration(500)
  .call(chart);
```

I was trying to find the max and min value, and set the domain and range to that values. This would have been static, but it didn't worked neither.

```
var chartY = {max: 0, min: 0};
$.each(data, function(i, e) {
    if ( parseInt(e.y, 10) > chartY.max) { chartY.max = parseInt(e.y, 10); }
    if ( parseInt(e.y, 10) < chartY.min) { chartY.min = parseInt(e.y, 10); }
});
chart
  .yDomain([chartY.min, 0, chartY.max])
  .yRange([chartY.min, 0, chartY.max]);
```

I have here a plnkr, maybe you guys have a solution. 
[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qL62AVNriwwJA4ydoH7V?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to display nicely by taking these steps:

1. Use latest version of NVD3 (1.8.6 - you were on 1.8.1)
2. Set the yDomain of the viewfinder: `chart.focus.yDomain([chartY.min, chartY.max])`
3. Update yDomain on focus change:

   ```
   let chartY = {max: 0, min: 0};
   $.each(data[0].values, function(i, e) {
       if ( parseInt(e.y, 10) > chartY.max) { chartY.max = parseInt(e.y, 10); }
       if ( parseInt(e.y, 10) < chartY.min) { chartY.min = parseInt(e.y, 10); }
   });
   chart.focus.yDomain([chartY.min, chartY.max])
   chart.yDomain([chartY.min, chartY.max]);

   const updateYDomain = (args) => {
     chartY = {max: 0, min: 0};
     const extent = [new Date(args.extent[0]).getTime(), new Date(args.extent[1]).getTime()];
     $.each(data[0].values, function(i, e) {
       const yVal = parseInt(e.y, 10);
       const xVal = parseInt(e.x, 10);

       if (yVal > chartY.max && xVal > extent[0] && xVal < extent[1]) { 
         chartY.max = yVal;
       }
       if (yVal < chartY.min  && xVal > extent[0] && xVal < extent[1]) {
         chartY.min = yVal;
       }
     });
     chart.yDomain([chartY.min, chartY.max]);
   }

   chart.focus.dispatch.on('brush', updateYDomain);
   chart.focus.dispatch.on('onBrush', updateYDomain);
   ```

Comment: Hi, this helped me with the focus-chart. But the big chart is trimmed between 0 and 100. Setting the yDomain to min and max will result in a static chart. The yAxis should update dynamicly to show the full height. 

Is it possible to get only the min and max of the current focused chard?
Thanks a lot.